# ActiveModel validation in separate File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

Is there a way to fulfil the validation with `ActiveModel` in a separate file? There is the possibility of **Custom Validations**

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator 
 … 
end
```

and call them with:`validates_with MyValidator`

But the default validation helper commands are not available in `MyValidator`.

All I need is to use: `validates_length_of` in a separate file and in best case called by various models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found quite an easy solution for that. 
Cause the custom validator class has to implement the method `validate(record)` the model is pass to the method as an ActiveRecord. All HelperMethods are avalible by calling inside this method:

```
record.validate_presence_of :attribute
```